# Understanding a proof for existence of set $A\subset R$ such that $|G- A|=\infty$ for ever open set $G\supset A$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I found an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4233925/266435.

I'm pasting that here to avoid switching tabs and I'm highlighting the parts that I need clarification on:

**quote**

You are indeed right that your set $A$ need be non-measurable and uncountable (after all any countable set is measurable).

Let $S \subseteq [0,1]$ be a non-measurable set. By the criteria that you stated there must exist $\epsilon_0 >0$ such that $|U \setminus S| > \epsilon_0$ for any open set $U$ containing $S$. I will use the notation $S +n$ for the set $S$ but translated by $n$, i.e. $S+n = \{s + n:s \in S\}$. Note that $|S| = |S+n|$ by translation invariance and $S+n \subseteq [n,n+1]$. Moreover $\color{red}{\text{$S+n$ has the property that any open set $U$ containing $S+n$ satisfies $|U \setminus (S+n)| \ge \epsilon_0$}}$.

Now consider
$S \cup (S+ 3)$.
I claim that $|U \setminus (S\cup (S+3))| \ge 2 \epsilon_0$ for any open set $U$ containing $S \cup (S+3)$. Indeed if $U$ is open and contains $S \cup (S+3)$ then since $S \subseteq [0,1]$ and $S+3 \subseteq [3,4]$ we have that $U \cap (-1,2)$ is an open set containing $S$ and $U \cap (2,5)$ is an open set containing $S+3$.  Thus
$$|(U\cap(-1,2)) \setminus S| \ge \epsilon_0\quad\text{and}\quad|(U \cap (2,5)) \setminus (S+3)| \ge \epsilon_0$$
And since $S\subseteq (-1,2)$ and $S+3\subseteq (2,5)$ we have that
$$\color{red}{|U \setminus (S \cup (S+3))| \ge |(U\cap(-1,2)) \setminus S|+|(U \cap (2,5)) \setminus (S+3)| \ge 2\epsilon_0}$$
Then consider $S \cup (S+3) \cup (S+6)$. A similar argument shows
$$|U\setminus (S \cup (S+3)\cup (S+6))| \ge 3 \epsilon_0$$
for any open set $U$ containing $S \cup (S+3)\cup (S+6)$.
Can you figure out the rest of the construction?

**unquote**

I think that one non trivial point in this answer is the claim that $U\setminus (S+n)|\ge \epsilon_0$. But I think I figured it out: Noting that

$(U-n)\setminus S+n \subset U\setminus (S+n)$, I use monotonicity and translational invariance of the outer measure.

I don't understand the second highlighted part. Why is it true? Can anyone please explain that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axler defines $A\subset \mathbb R$ to be Lebesgue measurable iff there exists a Borel set $B\subset A$ such that $A-B=\emptyset$.

Define $S=\{M\subset R: \forall A\subset R, |A|=|A\cap M|+|A\cap M^c|\}.$

It can be shown that $S$ is a $\sigma$ algebra.

**Claim**: $S$ contains open intervals.

**Pf**: Let $I=(a,b), a<b$. Take any $A\subset R$. By the definition of outer measure, given any $n\in \mathbb N$, there exists a sequence of open intervals $\{I_j\}, A\subset \bigcup I_k$ such that $\sum_k l(I_k)\lt |A|+\frac 1n.$

Define $J_n:= I\bigcap I_n, J_n'= I\bigcap I_n$.

By monotonicity, $|A\cap I|+|A\cap I^c|\le \sum_k\left (l(J_k)+l(J_k')\right)=\sum_kl(I_k)<|A|+1/n$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$.

Letting $n\to \infty$, it follows that $|A\cap I|+|A\cap I^c|\le |A|$. The other inequality follows by monotonicity. This proves that $I\in S$. $\tag{Q.E.D.}$

This implies that $S$ contains the Borel $\sigma$ algebra $\frak B$ on $R$ (as $\frak B$ is the smallest $\sigma$ algebra on $\mathbb R$ containing the open intervals.)

**Lemma**: $A\subset R$ is $S$- measurable iff for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists an open set $G\supset A$ such that $|G\setminus A|<\epsilon$.

**Pf**: $(\implies)$

$A$ is $S$- measurable. Suppose $|A|<\infty$. By the definition of outer measure, there exists an open set $G\supset A$ such that $|G|<|A|+\epsilon$.

Since $A$ is $S$-measurable, we have $|G|=|A\cap G|+|A^c\cap G|=|A|+|G\setminus A|\implies |G\setminus A|<\epsilon$.

If $|A|=\infty$, then we write $A=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} A\cap [-n,n]=\cup_n A_n$, where $A_n=A\cap [n,n+1]$. $|A_n|\lt \infty$ so by what we have proved just now, there exist open set $G_n\supset A_n$ such that $|G_n\setminus A_n|\lt \epsilon 2^{-{(n+1)}}$.

Set $G:= \bigcup_n G_n$.

$|G\setminus A|=|\cup_n (G_n\setminus A_n)|\le \sum_n |G_n\setminus A_n| <\epsilon$

For the other direction, it follows by Axler's theorem $2.71$, that there exists an $F_\sigma$ set $V\subset A$ such that $|A\setminus V|=0$. $V$ is a Borel set hence $V\in S$.

For any $E\subset R$, $|E\cap A|+|E\cap A^c|\le |E\cap V|+|E\cap V^c|=|E|$.
$\tag{Q.E.D}$

This shows the equivalence of $S$- measurable sets with Lebesgue measurable sets in Axler.

Now, if $E_k$'s are disjoint measurable sets, then for any $A\subset \cup E_k, k\in \mathbb N$, we have $|A|= \sum_k |A\cap E_k|$

(**pf**: using the definition of $S$.)

The questioned red part in the post follows by taking $A= U\setminus (S\cup (S+3)), E_1= (-1,2), E_2=(2,5), E_n=\emptyset \, \,\forall n\ge 3.$